# Accessing objects from within object?

Tags: javascript

This is probably a very newbish question, but I am learning javascript and working with pouchDB. I have a search function that returns something like:

```
{"total_rows":1,"rows":[{"id":"mydoc","score":0.7071067811865475,"doc":{"title":"Guess who?","text":"It's-a me, Mario!","_id":"mydoc","_rev":"1-21bd9b0c99791947618e98a23134b312"},"highlighting":{"text":"It's-a me, Mario!"}}]}
```

I can access the total_rows value easily obviously, but how would I access  the value of 'text'?

Comment: `blah.rows[0].doc.text`

Answer (score 1):

Simply with `x.rows[0].doc.text`.

Edit: To help you understand a little better what's happening here, you're accessing "sub children" with the `.` operator. We're asking for the `rows` array inside `x` and then specifying we want the first row (remember that arrays are 0-indexed, meaning the first element in an array is at position 0).

From there, we just access the `doc` child, and the `text` attribute it contains.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {"total_rows":1,"rows":[{"id":"mydoc","score":0.7071067811865475,"doc":{"title":"Guess who?","text":"It's-a me, Mario!","_id":"mydoc","_rev":"1-21bd9b0c99791947618e98a23134b312"},"highlighting":{"text":"It's-a me, Mario!"}}]};

console.log(obj.rows[0].doc.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please cchecck this

```
var abc = {
    "total_rows": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "mydoc",
            "score": 0.7071067811865475,
            "doc": {
                "title": "Guess who?",
                "text": "It's-a me, Mario!",
                "_id": "mydoc",
                "_rev": "1-21bd9b0c99791947618e98a23134b312"
            },
            "highlighting": {
                "text": "It's-a me, Mario!"
            }
        }
    ]
}

console.log(abc.rows[0].doc.text);
console.log(abc.rows[0].highlighting.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to identify each row by using 'id' to parse javascript object.

try this (javascript es6)

```
const obj = {"total_rows":1,"rows":[{"id":"mydoc","score":0.7071067811865475,"doc":{"title":"Guess who?","text":"It's-a me, Mario!","_id":"mydoc","_rev":"1-21bd9b0c99791947618e98a23134b312"},"highlighting":{"text":"It's-a me, Mario!"}}]}

const id = 'mydoc'
const text = obj.rows.find(item => item.id === id).doc.text
console.log(text)
```

javascript es5 or previous version

```
var obj = {"total_rows":1,"rows":[{"id":"mydoc","score":0.7071067811865475,"doc":{"title":"Guess who?","text":"It's-a me, Mario!","_id":"mydoc","_rev":"1-21bd9b0c99791947618e98a23134b312"},"highlighting":{"text":"It's-a me, Mario!"}}]};

var id = 'mydoc';
var text = obj.rows.find(function(item) { return item.id === id; }).doc.text;
console.log(text);
```